# IDE for Azure databricks

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, aws-databricks

I am exploring data bricks and writing all code in azure databricks notebooks.I read about IDEs such as data connect, vscode, pycharm, intell j. In real time people use IDEs or most of time people use data bricks notebooks. Please advise.

Regards,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are experienced on any IDE like Eclipse, IntelliJ, PyCharm, RStudio, Visual Studio Code, **Databricks Connect** allows you to connect with these IDEs to feel comfortable during development. Otherwise, you can simply use Notebook.

This official document on [Databricks Connect](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-connect.html#databricks-connect) will help you to understand how Databricks Connect works. Steps given to start writing your notebook in any supported IDE. Also, you will be come to know the differences between running using Databricks Connect versus running in a Databricks notebook.

Comment: thanks. is it possible to create a local environment (creating a local cluster) for data bricks instead of using databricks cluster. When we go for production then we will create a job cluster.
Reason is to avoid cost.

Comment: No, you can't run databricks notebook in local machine. Databricks is a PaaS service, therefore you need to use their clusters to run. But if you want to save cost and work on local environment, forget about Pycharm and VSC and install Jupyter notebook and create conda environment on your local machine. It gives you almost same user experience as in databricks notebook and especially designed for data analysis and ML.

Answer (score 3):

Since Feb 2023 Databricks is offering an official [Databricks extension for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=databricks.databricks). This allows you to edit your files in the IDE, sync them to a Databricks workspace and run them on a remote cluster.

This was the [official announcement](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2023/02/14/announcing-a-native-visual-studio-code-experience-for-databricks.html).

Comment: Would it work with IntelliJ? @febian

Answer (score 1):

You can use your favourite IDE with the dbx utility offered by Databricks. https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/index.html. As per official documentation dbx will replace Databricks connect.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned VSC (Visual studio code) and PyCharm. A few words from me:

- PyCharm has a paid version - premium, VSC is free.
- PyCharm has great support from JetBrains and VSC from Microsoft and the community.
- If you are a Python user, PyCHarm is probably a better choice.
- Two IDEs, i.e. PyCHarm and VSC, support Notebooks.

As for the official documentation, you will find there connection methods under the IDE. First I would start by looking at the one on the Databricks page:

- https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-connect.html#databricks-connect

Here's an article on Medium how you can connect Databricks to Pycharm:

- https://medium.com/@manju.sharan797/integrating-databricks-with-pycharm-ide-968d273d48d4

Finally, you have Microsoft's documentation and shown how to make the connection:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/databricks-connect

Go through the tutorials and decide which IDE is most friendly to you.

Comment: thanks. is it possible to create a local environment (creating a local cluster) for data bricks instead of using databricks cluster. When we go for production then we will create a job cluster.
Reason is to avoid cost.